# How does Rails routes.draw work behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am looking into following bit of code:

```
Helloworld::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase'

  resources :products do
    member do
      get 'short'
      post 'toggle'
    end

    collection do
      get 'sold'
    end
  end
end
```

Can somebody explain, how URLs are mapped to controllers behind the scenes?

The way I understand it:

1. Request object from Rack comes in;
2. `draw` evals its code block;
3. `match`, `resources` and etc are defined in the same scope as `draw`, thus those functions execute one after another, trying to match Request. If one of them does, it invokes right controller action.

Is this correct?

Thanks!